# WM_TIMER stops firing - environment to blame?

Tags: windows, timer

I've asked a variation of this question on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/853909/timer-in-application-stops-firing-vendor-is-blaming-our-server), but I thought it would be useful to get a development perspective on this.

We run several application servers for our customers, which run a commercial software application. Our customers access the application via a custom web-based application.

Recently, one 2012R2 server instance has given us real trouble; after a few minutes of processing, the application effectively freezes up - it's still running and responsive, but no data is processed. The application process starts taking up an entire virtual core of CPU time (i.e. there's 4 cores, it takes up 25%).

The application is a fairly old C++ binary. The vendor has tracked this down to an issue with a timer in the application, and they've said:

> Thread WM_TIMER messages are lowest-priority messages. The timer may
>   be delayed if the machine is under load. This isn't the case here as
>   the timer was permanently stopped. It also may be stopped through the
>   Shatter exploit or other malicious 3rd-party code.

In further dialogues, they're firmly of the belief this is a server or environmental issue, and not a bug in their code.

I'm a .NET developer, and in my limited experience a timer stopping is a rare event, and is usually caused by something in my code going wrong and causing the timer thread to crash or never exit.

Our server is patched and up to date, there's no direct user access, it has anti-virus (Kaspersky) and there's no sign of similar behaviour on any other server. I've taken the server offline and tried a "bare metal" virus scan, but nothing malicious was found.

I'm skeptical of the vendors analysis of the issue: we've had other problems with their application recently, and the high CPU usage feels more like an infinite loop issue to me - the timer fires, gets stuck on something and then never returns. However, I have no experience of `WM_TIMER`s, so my question is: is their reasoning sound, and that some other malicious application or process on the server could be causing the application timer to stop?

Comment: If Windows timer are stopping without any reason this would have been notice by a lot more people. It is more likely that some part of code is running havoc. Try process monitor from Microsoft and try to figure out what the application is doing.

Comment: On the other hand, the fact that the problem occurs on only a single instance does suggest an environmental problem.  Have you tried uninstalling the anti-virus software, to see if that makes any difference?